# How to upload files using the Feeds module?

Tags: nodes, feeds

I created a custom content type and I want to upload an XML file using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. Can somebody explain how to do the mapping correctly? Should I add a new importer or use a node importer?

I want to perform the upload using an XML file. I have unicode characters in my file.

I am not able to convert it to a CSV file. I have tried converting using Open Office but it is not working.

I find using feeds a bit complicated.

Are there other solutions to upload files into database?

Note: When I try to upload to says no new nodes created.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Feeds [XPath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser) module.

You may need this module if you would like to:

> - Import XML or HTML documents into nodes, users, taxonomy terms, or
>     regular database tables.
> - Scrape webpages like regular feed sources with scheduling, updating, and expiring.
> - Extract content from HTML documents to create a semantic data bank or mashup.

Below links will help you to set up.

- [Feeds XPath Parser](http://drupal.gatech.edu/handbook/feeds-xpath-parser), a full-fledged XML parser that utilizes the XPath syntax for scraping feeds.
- [Importing from XML](http://drupal.forhumanists.org/drupal-humanists-chapter-14-importing-data/importing-xml), from drupal.forhumanists.org.
- [Drupal 101: What I learnt from hours of troubleshooting Feeds](https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/drupal-101-what-i-learnt-from-hours-of-troubleshooting-feeds/).

Comment: Interesting links! Hope you don't mind I added the link-titles (feel free to rollback if you don't like the edited version ...).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) integration with the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module it is possible to import ***data blocks***.

***Data blocks*** are files that are located in a database repository, which is a (secured) directory on the web server that contains all data block files related to a specific [data source](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.data#datasources). The actual format of these files is dependent on which data provider or driver is being used for the data source:

- the most common format for these files is SQL, used for all supported data engines (Drupal, Oracle, PDO other than Drupal, Postgres or MSSQL), except for FrxFiles (XML Files).
- an alternative format for these files is XML.

For an illustration of how it is like to use [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) in combination with [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), have a look at the video about [How to import data and reports based on data as Drupal nodes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg4P747DmE8).

<sup>Disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of the [forena](/questions/tagged/forena) module.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I am able to create new node by creating a csv file using google spreadsheets instead of a xml file.I created a new feed importer and mapped the elements of feed to the appropriate fields.

Comment: Your question was about how to use Feeds using an XML file as input, **not** how to convert it to a CSV file ... If that's what you really wanted to ask, then update your question. But if you do that, it will become a question that IMO is "off topic" for this site ...